# HTTP Request from Web to Android

Tags: android, web, request, httprequest

How can I make an HTTP request from a web application (like node js) to an android app?

The goal is to read if the response is a success, for example, from Web to Web I make an HTTP request to the IP/URL and, if it returns 200, I have success. It would work as a "ping" to check if the android app is "alive".

Note: I don't know apps architecture

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using web sockets ( example here: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/ ) will help u to achieve it